maptloblib, adjust_text and errorbar
I use adjust_text to properly place text on the plot.
I don't want to have text placed on the connection lines between the points or the error bars.
My current best version for example code is:
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scienceplots  # type: ignore
from adjustText import adjust_text

plt.style.use(["science", "notebook"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50) * np.pi
y = np.sin(x)

errbar_container = ax.errorbar(x, y, xerr=0.25, yerr=0.05)

texts = []
for idx in range(0, len(x),2):
    texts.append(
        ax.annotate(
            idx,
            xy=(x[idx], y[idx]),
            size="large",
            zorder=100,
        )
    )

adjust_text(
    texts,
    x=x,
    y=y,
    expand=(2, 2),
    objects=[
        *[mpl.transforms.Bbox(seg) for seg in errbar_container.lines[-1][0].get_segments()],
        *[mpl.transforms.Bbox(seg) for seg in errbar_container.lines[-1][1].get_segments()],
    ],
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color="red"),
)

plt.show()


I also tried to use autoalign, only_move to e.g. shift only in x- direction as mentioned here but the options seem to be ignored as well.
How do I ensure that text is not placed on the error bars and the connection lines?
EDIT 1:
When I rerun above code I realized that the problem is actually because of the plot style from scienceplots I used. (When I tried it I used a jupyter notebook where the style was already set.)
EDIT 2:
Link to GitHub issue: https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText/issues/190

I just ran your example and as far as I can see it achieves what you are looking for.  Can you include an image of what you get and say what about it is not desired?

@RuthC, I just realized that the problem is becuase of the use of scienceplots. The problem I have is the placement of the numbers 0, 2 and 4 on the line.
